# Where is my program waiting?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, blocking

I have a Delphi 10 multithreading application with blocking calls. When I exit it is sometimes not unloaded from RAM and Delphi debugger isn't stopped.

How (tool, method) to detect in which routine is my app waiting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Hit the [Pause](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Pause) button (Run, Program Pause)
2. Show the [Threads window](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Thread_Status) (View, Debug Windows, Threads or `Ctrl+Alt+V`)
3. Double-click on each thread in turn and inspect the [call stack](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Call_Stack_Window) (View, Debug Windows, Call Stack or `Ctrl+Alt+S`)
4. Look for your routines in the call stack and evaluate the evidence you see before you when perusing the code at the top of the call stack, but in your source files

Sometimes it is more informative to run the above steps with [Debug DCUs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiling) enabled (Project, Options..., Delphi Compiler, Compiling, Use debug .dcus), and [runtime packages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Runtime_Packages_(Options)) disabled (Project, Options..., Packages, Runtime Packages, Link with runtime packages)

Comment: Thank you. Didn'n know about this. This window shows me 5 threads: 4 of them with State=Stopped, Status=Unknown and one with State=Stopped, Status=Stepped.

Comment: Find the main thread, and see what it is blocking on. Take it from there. You can name your threads to make it easier to know which is the main thread.

Comment: [Naming threads](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Naming_a_Thread) documentation

Comment: BTW, the main thread is typically at the top of the thread list

Comment: Oh sure, just call something akin to `TThread.NameThreadForDebugging('UI thread');`. I do this as the first line in the project source and it seems to work peachy.

Comment: Do review [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.NameThreadForDebugging)

Comment: That would work too. I don't recall having the need to refer to the `CurrentThread` property, thanks to `NameThreadForDebugging` being a static class procedure. Though it should be said I was doing it in C++ - not that I expect that to make any difference.